# How variabilizing a part of the name of the data table used by QGIS ? I would like to use the same QGIS project for each year I'm studying

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-variable

I created a map and a page layout for year 2018:

[image: A map for year 2018]

It relies on data of the table `temp_desendettement_communes_2018` (from a *PostGIS* database).

[image: the data table extracted for 2018]

I wish using the same *QGIS* project for other years, and change only a parameter to choose `temp_desenttement_communes_<year>` as data table name for source. (and then use this parameter to correct the title of the map too).

(*note: things would been simpler if year was a column of a table `temp_desendettement_communes`, but it's not the case)*

How to declare and use a parameter in a *QGIS* project that applies on a table name?

Comment: I suppose you can't change the way that table is generated otherwise it woul'd be simplier to add a field named Year and remove it from the table name. After it's a simple use of a filter that could use a parameter.

Comment: @Billy34 I agree with you about a Year field (I wrote it in my post), but it's not possible : the software is done that way that it only give me a table having the results of a single year, and suffixed by that year. I can't change it.

Comment: Maybe create a union query that will generate this structure. Something like `SELECT *,2018 AS year FROM table_2018 UNION SELECT *,2019 AS year FROM table_2019 ...`

Comment: I think it's possible in a virtual layer

Comment: @Billy34 It's not possible. At the step I am, when my treatment is called, it has only a single table available : a temporary one, containing the data we are focusing on.

Comment: Except from a two step process I don't know. First import database in a layer using maybe Processing (you then can use parameters) and then display this imported layer

Comment: Or save your project file as a .qgs (uncompressed) and tweak it using a text editor (database name should appear in clear text somewhere in this file). You can then prepare several qgs files for the different years

Answer (score 1):

You could use project-wide Macros, which does what you ask for on project load.

A very naive approach, using an input dialog to change the data source table name suffix (the year); `_setYear` then looks for a **loaded layer** with the **suffix-less** `base_name` and changes its data source (i.e. PG table name) and layer display name to `base_name + year`:

- In `<QGIS> | Project | Properties...`, switch to `Macros`

  - enable `Python Macros`
  - replace code with

    ```
    from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsDataSourceUri
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit

    base_name = 'temp_desenttement_communes_'

    def openProject():
        _setYear()
        pass

    def saveProject():
        pass

    def closeProject():
        pass


    def _setYear():
        popup = QWidget()
        year, ok = QInputDialog.getText(popup, "Set Source","Year:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if ok and year != '':
            layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

            for layer in layers:
                if layer.name().startswith(base_name):
                    provider = layer.dataProvider()
                    uri = provider.uri()
                    uri.setTable(base_name+year)
                    layer.setDataSource(uri.uri(), base_name+year, provider.name(), provider.ProviderOptions())

                    return
    ```

Save your work, reload the project and enter a new year. Pretty sure you can write a tiny Plugin with this logic to cascade the changes down to the Print Composer.

---

Note that you need to allow QGIS to execute Python macros; go to

- `<QGIS> | Settings | Options...` and switch to `General`

  - choose a setting for `Enable macros`

`Ask` is fine; whenever QGIS loads the Project (or any project with macros enabled) it will ask you with a pop-up notification on the main screen for activation; if you want to switch the layer source hit `Enable Macros`, otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: To any experienced pyqgis user: feel free to improve the code in my answer to anything more sophisticated; I script in pyqgis only for these little riddles during breaks.

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of such possibilities. QGis really rocks :-)